# Django 5 star rating system is not saving reviews and rating

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I build a model for user reviews and rating. And made the form for my model , then I call the form in my views . When i click on button from detail page to get the "**rate.html**" it get me there but did not save the data from there and give me this error .

```html
IntegrityError at /product/new-shoes/rate/
NOT NULL constraint failed: products_review.user_id
```

my **models.py** is:

```html
class Review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=3000 , blank=True)
    rate = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=RATE_CHOICES)
    likes= models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    dislikes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.full_name
```

my forms.py is:

```html
class RateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'materialize-textarea'}),required=False)
    rate = forms.ChoiceField(choices=RATE_CHOICES, widget=forms.Select(),required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields= ('text', 'rate')
```

my **views.py** is:

```html
class RateView(CreateView):
    form_class = RateForm
    template_name = 'rate.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.product = Product.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('products:detail', kwargs={'slug': self.object.product.slug})
```

and my rate.html is:

```html
{% extends "base.html"%}
{% block content %}

              <form method="POST" action="" role="form" class="col s12">
                {% csrf_token %}
               <div class="input-field col s12">
                  {{ form.rate }}
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                  {{ form.text }}
                <label for="textarea1">Opinion</label>
              </div>

              <button type="submit" name="action" class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons left">star</i>Rate</button>
            </form>


{% endblock %}
```

my urls.py for the view is:

```html
path('<slug:slug>/rate/', RateView.as_view(), name='rate-product1'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the user field is not being set. You can do this in the `form_valid` function:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    ...
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    form.instance.product = Product.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
    ...
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: now i want the reviews to be shown with the product in the product detail page how to do this can you guide me

Comment: The docs have you covered https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this :-

```
class Review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product , on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=3000 , blank=True)
    rate = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=RATE_CHOICES)
    likes= models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    dislikes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.full_name
```

**What i have changed** :-

I have set `null` = `True` in your *product variable*, which is with `ForeignKey`

Comment: Did you make `migrations` after changes ?